# How to flag reference to undefined array element in php

Tags: php

When we try to assign/access an undefined index of an array PHP will throw a notice:

```
<?php
    $array = array(0=>array('title'=>'Titre','content'=>array()));
    $value = $array[1]['content']; // assignment, warning is issued
```

> Warning: Undefined array key 1 in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 5

However, when using an undefined index as a reference, there is no warning issued. It looks like taking a reference to an undefined array element will create that element if you then use that reference, without any warning.

How can I change this behavior so PHP actually throws a warning/notice that the index is undefined?

```
<?php
    $array = array(0=>array('title'=>'Titre','content'=>array()));
    $refvalue = &$array[1]['content']; // taking a reference, no warning
    $refvalue['bozo']='baz';
    print_r($array);
```

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => Titre
                [content] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [content] => Array
                    (
                        [bozo] => baz
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear that this is not a (well known) duplicate. You can always rollback if you don't approve these edits.

Comment: FYI: This behaviour has been in all the previous PHP versions as well - [demo](https://3v4l.org/JDCcU)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change this behavior so PHP actually throws a warning/notice that the index is undefined?

Well the obvious answer is to just check first:

```
$array = [...];
if (!isset($array[1]['content'])) {
    trigger_error('no such thing', E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

But I think a much more elegant solution is to use the null coalesce operator with the [throw-as-expression](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/throw_expression) feature introduced in PHP 8. This will stop it from happening, which is probably what you want:

```
$array = [...];
$ref = &$array[1]['content'] ?? throw new Exception('no such thing');
```

If you want to allow it to happen, and just report on it, then generate an error instead of an exception:

```
$array = [...];
$ref = &$array[1]['content'] ?? trigger_error('no such thing', E_USER_WARNING);
```

Comment: Well, the goal is to detect issue, I guess it will work if you can force yourself to always test references.

Comment: This answer fails in one very specific situation: If the referenced index is defined, but explicitly set to a `null` value. It is probably the best option though, just be aware of this one extremely specific catch.